# What's the meaning of this Unbound Local error in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, compiler-errors

I have the following code :

```
def Menu():
    try : choice = int(input("Enter your choice : "))
    except : 
        print('Invalid choice .')
        Menu()

    if choice>=6 or choice <=0: 
        print('Invalid choice .')
        Menu()
    else:print('OK')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Menu()
```

When I enter a number between 1-5 , it print Ok . If I enter anything else , it reports invalid choice. Perfect till now . But when I have entered incorrect choice in the first attempt and try to enter correct choice on second attempt , it gives me this stupid error.

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'choice' referenced before assignment
```

What's wrong ? What is happening ? How am I messing such a simple code?

Comment: If you hit the exception, you don't assign anything to `choice`.

Comment: @tdelaney But I am entering the input . Why is it not being assigned ?

Comment: It doesn't give me any error. I entered incorrect choice on first attempt(8), then I entered 2 on the second attempt. It works perfectly!

Comment: It is assigned in the inner Menu call, not the outer one, there are different ones

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357). `choice` is no defined if the `except` occurs. Add a `return` after `Menu()`

Comment: On invalid choice, you call `Menu()` again but its "choice" is a local variable that is destroyed when the inner function returns. You would need to return the choice in the inner function and then assign it to `choice` in the outer function for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is

1. in first `Menu` call : enter
2. in first `Menu` call : input a non-digit => Exception, **nothing is assigned to choice**
3. in first `Menu` call : execute second `Menu` call
4. in first `Menu` call : in second `Menu` : give correct input (1-5) else executed, end of method
5. in first `Menu` call : come back, move to if/else : **choice is not defined in the `Menu` call**

---

DO never re-call a method inside itselt just do *reset/restart* its purpose, the way is to use a `while` loop

```
def Menu():
    choice = ''
    while not choice.isdigit() or not (0<int(choice)<6):
        choice = input("Enter your choice : ")

    print("Choice is ok", choice)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out . How to work around this ?

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit i've edit